# GROK pattern cannot parse logs

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I want to launch the ELK-stack for gathering syslog from all my network equipment - Cisco, F5, Huawei, CheckPoint, etc. While experimenting with Logstash, writing grok patterns.

Below is an example of messages from Cisco ASR:

> <191>Oct 30 16:30:10 evlogd: [local-60sec10.950] [cli 30000 debug] [8/0/30501  cliparse.c:367] [context: local, contextID: 1]  [software internal system syslog] CLI command [user root, mode [local]ASR5K]: show ims-authorization policy-control statistics\u0000
>
> <190>Oct 30 16:30:10 evlogd: [local-60sec10.959] [cli 30005 info] [8/0/30501  _commands_cli.c:1792] [software internal system syslog] CLI session ended for Security Administrator root on device /dev/pts/7\u0000
>
> <190>Oct 30 16:30:10 evlogd: [local-60sec10.981] [snmp 22002 info] [8/0/4550  trap_api.c:930] [software internal system syslog] Internal trap notification 53 (CLISessEnd) user root privilege level Security Administrator ttyname /dev/pts/7\u0000
>
> <190>Oct 30 16:30:12 evlogd: [local-60sec12.639] [cli 30004 info] [8/0/30575  cli_sess.c:127] [software internal system syslog] CLI session started for Security Administrator root on device /dev/pts/7 from 192.168.1.1\u0000
>
> <190>Oct 30 16:30:12 evlogd: [local-60sec12.640] [snmp 22002 info] [8/0/30575  trap_api.c:930] [software internal system syslog] Internal trap notification 52 (CLISessStart) user root privilege level Security Administrator ttyname /dev/pts/7\u0000

All of them matching with my pattern [here](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) and [here](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result).

```
<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>%{DATA:month} %{DATA:monthday} %{TIME:time} %{WORD:device}: \[%{WORD:facility}\-%{HOSTNAME}\] \[%{WORD:service} %{POSINT} %{WORD:priority}\] \[%{DATA}\] ?(\[context: %{DATA:context}, %{DATA}\])?%{SPACE}?(\[%{DATA}\] )%{GREEDYDATA:message}\\u0000
```

But my simple logstash configuration return tag `_grokparsefailure` (or `_grokparsefailure_sysloginput` if I use GROK in syslog input plugin), and doesn't parse my log.

**Config using GROK-filter**

```
input { udp {
    port => 5140
    type => syslog } }

filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
     grok {
      match => ["message", "<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>%{DATA:month} %{DATA:monthday} %{TIME:time} %{WORD:device}: \[%{WORD:facility}\-%{HOSTNAME}\] \[%{WORD:service} %{POSINT} %{WORD:priority}\] \
[%{DATA}\] ?(\[context: %{DATA:context}, %{DATA}\])?%{SPACE}?(\[%{DATA}\] )%{GREEDYDATA:response}\\u0000"]
    }
  }
}

output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }
```

Output:

```
{
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "172.17.0.1",
    "@timestamp" => 2018-10-31T09:46:51.121Z,
       "message" => "<190>Oct 31 15:46:51 evlogd: [local-60sec51.119] [snmp 22002 info] [8/0/4550 <sitmain:80> trap_api.c:930] [software internal system syslog] Internal trap notification 53 (CLISessEnd) user kiwi privilege level Security Administrator ttyname /dev/pts/7\u0000",
          "type" => "syslog",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure"
    ]
}
```

**Config syslog-input-plugin:**

```
input {
  syslog {
    port => 5140
    grok_pattern => "<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>%{DATA:month} %{DATA:monthday} %{TIME:time} %{WORD:device}: \[%{WORD:facility}\-%{HOSTNAME}\] \[%{WORD:service} %{POSINT} %{WORD:priority}\] \[%{DATA
}\] ?(\[context: %{DATA:context}, %{DATA}\])?%{SPACE}?(\[%{DATA}\] )%{GREEDYDATA:response}\\u0000"
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
       }
```

Output:

```
{
          "severity" => 0,
        "@timestamp" => 2018-10-31T09:54:56.871Z,
          "@version" => "1",
              "host" => "172.17.0.1",
           "message" => "<191>Oct 31 15:54:56 evlogd: [local-60sec56.870] [cli 30000 debug] [8/0/22400 <cli:8022400> cliparse.c:367] [context: local, contextID: 1]  [software internal system syslog] CLI command [user kiwi, mode [local]ALA3_ASR5K]: show subscribers ggsn-only sum apn osmp\u0000",
              "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure_sysloginput"
    ],
}
```

What am I doing wrong? And can someone help fix it?

PS Tested on logstash 2.4.1 and 5

Comment: By the way, it's not possible to see the patterns working online.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the online-debuggers, logstash's GROK didn't like my \\u0000 at the end of pattern. 
With single backslash all is working.

Right grok-filter is:

```
<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>%{DATA:month} %{DATA:monthday} %{TIME:time} %{WORD:device}: \[%{WORD:facility}\-%{HOSTNAME}\] \[%{WORD:service} %{POSINT} %{WORD:priority}\] \[%{DATA}\] ?(\[context: %{DATA:context}, %{DATA}\])?%{SPACE}?(\[%{DATA}\] )%{GREEDYDATA:message}\u0000
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problem. The workaround is just to received those logs from routers/firewalls/switches to a `syslog-ng` server and then forward to the logstash.

Following is a sample configuration for `syslog-ng`,

```
source s_router1 {
    udp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(1514));
    tcp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(1514));
};

destination d_router1_logstash { tcp("localhost",port(5045)); };

log { source(s_router1); destination(d_router1_logstash); };
```